# how to check if RLock in python 3 is acquired by any thread

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python 2, I'd use:

```
is_locked = rlock._RLock__count > 0
```

And this is since `RLock` doesn't give me the functionality that a regular `Lock` object has, i.e. a `locked()` method.
In python 3, even the private variable `_RLock__count`doesn't exist.

Comment: Note that even if the lock is not acquired at the time of checking, there's no guarantee that attempt to acquire it will not block -- because there's a race condition if another thread tries to lock it at the same time. If you intend to acquire the lock if it's not locked then just acquire it with `blocking=False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the `__count` instance attribute was renamed to `_count` when moving to the new version of Python. To provide a simple API, a `CustomRLock` class has been devised and is demonstrated in the example below. It should allow you to find out if the lock has been acquired by any thread (including the current thread).

```
import random
import threading


def main():
    lock = CustomRLock()
    if random.randrange(2):
        lock.acquire()
    print('Lock was', end='')
    if not lock.acquired:
        print(' not', end='')
    print(' acquired.')


class CustomRLock(threading._PyRLock):

    @property
    def acquired(self):
        return bool(self._count)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that there may be a race condition if the `acquired` property is checked and an action is committed that expects the lock to be in a certain state. Between checking and executing some code, the lock's condition can change.

Comment: that's a problem that's inherent in all multithreaded programming. If that's an issue, then you don't "Look Before You Leap", rather you try acquiring the lock, and see if you managed ("Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission").

Comment: @Loquacious That is precisely why I prefer my first answer. Your application allows you to look before you leap without any problems? If you do need avoid the race condition, it would be nice to see an answer similar to the first that does not have the two problems you pointed out. Such a solution could potentially be useful to more people.

Comment: Is no one here bothered by the fact that this uses an internal API, as indicated by the underscore before `_count`?

Comment: _count doesn't exist on the Windows implementation of RLock. _recursion_count is a possible substitute -- a great illustration of why you shouldn't use internal parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider trying to acquire the lock in non-blocking mode and then releasing the lock if acquired and it is appropriate to do so. The following examples show how this can be done:

```
import random
import threading


def main():
    lock = Test().lock
    print('The RLock was', end='')
    if lock.acquire(False):
        lock.release()
    else:
        print(' not', end='')
    print(' acquired by the main thread.')


class Test(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__lock = threading.RLock()

    def run(self):
        if random.randrange(2):
            self.__lock.acquire()

    @property
    def lock(self):
        self.start()
        self.join()
        return self.__lock


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It does solve my problem, but it still has two flaws:
1. It temporarily acquires the lock, which is not always acceptable.
2. It only works when run from a thread that *isn't* the one that acquired the lock.

Comment: @Loquacious I've provided another answer that should solve your problem. This answer is being left as-is since at least one person has found it to be useful. Also, it should not introduce any race conditions to my knowledge.

Comment: Yes, I'm the one who found it useful :)